# How to test that a a time series follows a Markov process?

Tags: statistical-inference

I am searching for a statistical test  that tells  wether a finite-alphabet time series is a Markov process of a given order or not.

Comment: just for clarification (I have no answer anyway): for "order" of the process you mean the number of states and not the number of previous states in the process's memory, right?

Comment: I actually meant the memory of the process.

Comment: but in this case every (finite) sequence may be seen as the result of a suitable Markow process, with its order equal to the length of the sequence :-)

Comment: Assume that you fix (or upper-bound) the order beforehand.